# What is the role of the paragogic heh when used with the second person as in Psalm 108:5 (ר֣וּמָה)?

Tags: hebrew, psalms, grammar

What is the role of the paragogic heh when used with the second person as in Psalm 108:5 (ר֣וּמָה)?

When used with the first person it as a cohortative meaning, but what's the difference with the imperative (second person)?

Comment: It is in Psalms 108:6, not 5

Comment: Fassberg's opinion seems to fit Gen 39.7 where Potiphar's wife tempts Joseph to sleep with her:
שׁכבה עמי

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few opinions in the literature (see [Fassberg's paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/27913398?uid=3738240&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102543033923) on the lengthened imperative which has a *huge* number of excellent references). A summary of the opinions presented looks more or less as follows:

- None
- Emphasis (paralleled to the Arabic), similar to the cohortitive meaning
- Emphasis originally, although the distinction became more stylistic than functional
- Euphony
- Used as a polite/honorary form, respecting the subject (usually God or a priest etc.), potentially meaning "please"
- The insightful opinion of Fassberg himself, that the lengthened imperative is used when the action (i.e. the result) or object of the imperative is of interest or closely related to the speaker, or if the speaker will partake in that particular action (which is then often followed by the 1st person plural cohortative)

Comment: Thank you. Is this the article you are refering to ? _“The Lengthened Imperative קָטְלָה and the Regular Imperative קְטֹל in Biblical Hebrew,” Hebrew Through the Ages in Memory of Shoshanna Bahat [Studies in Language II], 71-77. Ed. M. Bar-Asher. Jerusalem: Academy of Hebrew Language, 1997 (in Hebrew). Translated into Korean in Linguistic Studies in Biblical and Post-Biblical Hebrew: A Collection of Articles Translated from Hebrew into Korean, trans. Mi-Sop Park. Seoul: Han DL, 1999."_

Comment: Presumably it has the same content, although the title looks a little different. The article I'm familiar with can be found http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/27913398?uid=3738240&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102543033923 or http://muse.jhu.edu/login?auth=0&type=summary&url=/journals/hebrew_studies/v040/40.fassberg.pdf

Comment: In support of Fassberg's views, see also Jan Joosten, "[The Lengthened Imperative with Accusative Suffix in Biblical Hebrew](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/zatw.1999.111.3.423)", *Zeitschrift für die Alttestamentliche Wissenschaft*, Volume 111, Issue 3, (1999): 423–426.